# I keep getting truncated core files in docker container for my Golang app

Tags: docker, go, core-file

I got my Go-based app to dump core on fatal errors inside docker but the core files are getting truncated.  I have set my ulimit on core files to be unlimited (`ulimit -c unlimited`) on both on docker host and I passed setting into docker run command but again core files half the expected size of around 110MB instead of 260MB core tools like gdb and delve have trouble reading them.

```
docker run --ulimit core=-1 ...
```

I am getting core files, so I know `GOTRACEBACK=crash` and my kernel `core_pattern` setting is set correctly. I get proper cores when I run my app w/o docker.